# Using game related images, wallpapers etc in commercial design products

Tags: copyright, trademark

I am looking to expand my graphic design services more into the gaming & esports space. For example, esports jerseys, Twitch.tv streaming graphics, web themes & templates, etc.

In many cases users love to have specific game related assets (sprites, character artwork etc) including in the designs. There is currently to my knowledge no Shutter Stock type exchange for officially licensing game related assets. Most hobbyists and gaming graphic artists typically grab wallpapers and screenshots publicly available for a given game (often from the official developer website) and modify them to their needs. However this is a niche space that I believe flies under the radar or concern of the larger companies.

Many game developers will offer a "Media" repository on their official website, with artwork and wallpapers for their game. However there's usually no permitted use or licensing info.

Is there a legal way to use game related artwork or wallpapers in commercial products or graphic design services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Legally*, yes. Get permission for use from the copyright holder. Best to get it *in writing*.

To the best of my knowledge there is *no way*, other than *explicit permission*, to commercially use the intellectual property (IP) owned by someone other than yourself and remain "infringement free".

There is no "loophole" or "fair use" caveat if you are reselling IP you do not own. It does not matter if it is related to a game, a song, a painting, a writing, a lawn chair, a toothbrush.....

Comment: I shall try contacting different developers (via their websites) regarding this and see how it goes, thanks for the suggestion. It is a shame especially considering the rise of the gaming landscape (particularly esports) there is very little available as to licensing materials.

Comment: I don't really understand that mindset... if something is popular, or more revenue-generating, then you feel copyright laws should be more lax???

Comment: No I meant, I wish there were more official means in place, such as Shutterstock-type licensing etc. So far in the gaming space there are basically publicly available artwork, wallpaper and graphics for "fans" to use for personal use, but no official way to license. Hopefully that will change though.